# PhpBB attachment files

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

In the `phpbb_attachments` table of the database, we can find link between file on server and real name.

Example :

```
Physical filename = 2_8f375562c92996d3272ea0b43947b0e7  
Real_filename = blah.jpg
```

Then if I try to open the file `2_8f375562c92996d3272ea0b43947b0e7` which is stored on server (by renaming with .jpg), its content is not the real image : the image is like "encrypted" !

**Is there an attachment content encryption when storing attachment on server ?**
*If so, how to manually see the real content of an attachment?*

Comment: I am unable to replicate this. I can pull files from my `files` directory, add the appropriate extension and open them just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script in the phpBB knowledge base that you can use to back up all attachments with their original file name - https://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/backing-up-attachments-with-their-original-filenames/